# PGP identity for Telegram account

Tags: pgp, openpgp, telegram

I want to use a Telegram username instead of an email address in a PGP key.

Is there an agreed upon standard for doing this? Do you know a software or service which acts as a bridge to connect a PGP email address to a Telegram account?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

PGP/GPG can be used on any system, albeit it's standard setup expects an email. If you want a **UID** that is other than an email you can force one with the ***quick*** commands which do not perform any checking of syntax and accept entries as literal.

For example, given a GPG key set up with and email of *qwerty@qwerty.com* you can modify it with:

```
gpg --quick-add-uid qwerty@qwerty.com Any_ID_you_like
gpg --quick-set-primary-uid qwerty@qwerty.com Any_ID_you_like
gpg --edit-key Any_ID_you_like
uid
sec  rsa3072/50993F2F1D5B88B0
     created: 2022-08-03  expires: 2022-08-04  usage: SC  
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa3072/5B5C6BE09EC853C2
     created: 2022-08-03  expires: 2022-08-04  usage: E   
[ultimate] (1). Any_ID_you_like
[ultimate] (2) qwerty <qwerty@qwerty.com>

gpg> uid 2

sec  rsa3072/50993F2F1D5B88B0
     created: 2022-08-03  expires: 2022-08-04  usage: SC  
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa3072/5B5C6BE09EC853C2
     created: 2022-08-03  expires: 2022-08-04  usage: E   
[ultimate] (1). Any_ID_you_like
[ultimate] (2)* qwerty <qwerty@qwerty.com>

gpg> deluid
Really remove this user ID? (y/N) y

sec  rsa3072/50993F2F1D5B88B0
     created: 2022-08-03  expires: 2022-08-04  usage: SC  
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa3072/5B5C6BE09EC853C2
     created: 2022-08-03  expires: 2022-08-04  usage: E   
[ultimate] (1). Any_ID_you_like
gpg> save

gpg -k Any_ID_you_like
pub   rsa3072 2022-08-03 [SC] [expires: 2022-08-04]
      45F49B3D98AE20256E5C180C50993F2F1D5B88B0
uid           [ultimate] Any_ID_you_like
sub   rsa3072 2022-08-03 [E] [expires: 2022-08-04]
```